# How to decode encoded data in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search for search in my Web API.
Indexer Source used: SQL Azure Database
The column that is being indexed has special characters. Hence I am encoding the data when pushing into Azure Search.

Is there a way to decode the data as part of retrieval from Azure Search?

Only documentation I could find online on decoding in Azure Search is for [decoding metadata of blobs.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexer-field-mappings/#base64DecodeFunction)

Answer (score 1):

The question involves using a table column that may contain key-invalid characters as the document key. 
To make this work, define a field mapping and apply base64Encode function. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexer-field-mappings/#base64EncodeFunction

Note that Azure Search will store the encoded value as the key of your document. If you actually want to search / filter on the original value, fork the original value in your field mappings, like this:

```
"fieldMappings" : [ 
  { "sourceFieldName" : "Id", "targetFieldName" : "Id", "mappingFunction" : { "name" : "base64Encode" } },
  { "sourceFieldName" : "Id", "targetFieldName" : "OriginalId" }
]
```

HTH!